# Run mongodb script once to insert initial data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, patch

I have a chicken and egg problem with my node server in which you need to have a user with a certain role that has certain permissions to be able to log in and start creating more users, roles, etc.

I would like to initialize the database such that I create an initial ADMIN role and initial admin user that has that role.

I.E. started with a script and ran into problems:

```
use mydb

db.roles.insert({
  name: "ADMIN_ROLE",
  description: "Administrative role",
  permissions: ['ALL']
});

db.users.insert({
  username: "admin",
  password: "password",
  role: ??? (get ADMIN_ROLE _id from above)
});
```

Basically I ran into a couple of problems:
1. not really sure if I can script like this.
2. How to get ADMIN_ROLE id to store in new admin user

Another idea:
Write a quick node app that connects to mongodb and inserts the proper stuff.  Anyone done this before.

And yet another:
Does anything like ruby rake exist for node/mongo.  I.E. the initial seed may not be the only data I need to 'manually' mess with.  I.E. I might need to patch the database at some point in time.  Would be nice to create patch #1 as the initial seed, and then be able to write future patches if necessary and be able to.  I.E. anything like rake migrate?

Any other ideas on how to seed a mongo database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shoot just found this:

https://github.com/visionmedia/node-migrate

and

https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-migrate

Exactly what I was looking for.